# Emulate cross-site requests in localhost

Tags: node.js, localhost, cors, server, emulation

Is there a way to make cross-site requests in the localhost? To emulate a different domain? How do you make an application, for example to do JSON-P or CORS and test it in your local machine without having an actual domain?

I am using NodeJS and WebStorm.

Thank you.

Comment: Start two servers at once, each listening on a separate port -- `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3001`, for example. One for the page making the request, the other for the requested resource.

Comment: But the domain will be the same. Does the browser treat different ports as a different domain?

Comment: "Cross-site" is determined by the origin, not just the domain/hostname, which also includes the protocol and port. [MDN: Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Didn't know port will treated as a different origin.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can access your site from both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`, load the page via `localhost` and have that page access `http://127.0.0.1`. I can't guarantee this triggers cross-origin in all cases, but it was working for me with iframes.